# VBA Open workbook error?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using vba to try and open a workbook (if it's not already open).

The problem I have is sometimes the workbook can be opened by another user, so if the workbook is locked then i want to present the user an option to open the workbook in read only.

Code:

```
'Open Planner
On Error Resume Next
Set WB = Workbooks("2017 Planner.xlsx")
On Error GoTo 0
If WB Is Nothing Then 'open workbook if not open
On Error GoTo Message4
Set WB = Workbooks.Open("G:\BUYING\Food Specials\2. Planning\1. Planning\1. Planner\8. 2017\2017 Planner.xlsx", Password:="samples", WriteResPassword:="samples", UpdateLinks:=False)
Message4:
Dim answer2 As Integer
answer2 = MsgBox("Oooops!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "We had trouble opening the planner with Read/Write access. We can open the file in Read-Only but this means the planner won't automatically be updated. Would you like to continue?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Notice")
If answer2 = vbNo Then
Exit Sub
Else
Set WB = Workbooks.Open("G:\BUYING\Food Specials\2. Planning\1. Planning\1. Planner\8. 2017\2017 Planner.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True)
End If
End If
```

For some reason i get an error 1004 on this line:

```
Set WB = Workbooks.Open("G:\BUYING\Food Specials\2. Planning\1. Planning\1. Planner\8. 2017\2017 Planner.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True)
```

Comment: Have you tried my code?

Comment: You provided `Password:="samples"` in your first call to open but not in the second.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dim link as string

link= "G:\BUYING\Food Specials\2. Planning\1. Planning\1. Planner\8. 2017\2017 Planner.xlsx"
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=link, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for check, try to put the file in some directory that hasn't got any special characters.

ie :  C:\workbooks

Make sure about the permissions to open the file.

Answer (score 0):

You could test if it's open already:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim sFilePath As String
    Dim wrkBk As Workbook

    sFilePath = "G:\BUYING\Food Specials\2. Planning\1. Planning\1. Planner\8. 2017\2017 Planner.xlsx"

    If WorkBookIsOpen(sFilePath) Then
        Set wrkBk = Workbooks.Open(sFilePath, ReadOnly:=True)
    Else
        Set wrkBk = Workbooks.Open(sFilePath)
    End If

End Sub

Public Function WorkBookIsOpen(FullFilePath As String) As Boolean

    Dim ff As Long

    On Error Resume Next

    ff = FreeFile()
    Open FullFilePath For Input Lock Read As #ff
    Close ff
    WorkBookIsOpen = (Err.Number <> 0)

    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

As the function `WorkBookIsOpen` returns a boolean and the `ReadOnly` property expects a boolean you could use this shorter procedure:

```
Sub Test2()

    Dim sFilePath As String
    Dim wrkBk As Workbook

    sFilePath = "G:\BUYING\Food Specials\2. Planning\1. Planning\1. Planner\8. 2017\2017 Planner.xlsx"

    Set wrkBk = Workbooks.Open(sFilePath, ReadOnly:=WorkBookIsOpen(sFilePath))

End Sub
```